# 301 Issues with 2 URLs on same webspace

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains, the old domain is mjvandco.co.uk and he wants this redirecting to mjvlaw.co.uk. I have both pointing to the same webspace but when I test the URLs using https://httpstatus.io/ I get different results.

I have the following in my htaccess along with other stuff, but this is the redirect content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mjvlaw\.co\.uk 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


# Remove .html (excluding blog)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog(.*)$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The only URL that now is not right is this one: http://www.mjvlaw.co.uk/. I used [this site](https://httpstatus.io/)

https://mjvlaw.co.uk - goes to https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk
http://mjvlaw.co.uk - goes to https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk
http://www.mjvlaw.co.uk - not work as does not go to https
https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk - fine

However, when I do the same for the old domain it all works as it should and every one below goes too https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk.

https://www.mjvandco.co.uk
https://mjvandco.co.uk
http://mjvandco.co.uk
http://www.mjvandco.co.uk

Am I doing something stupid here? Should I create another webspace and have one folder for the old domain and what for the current one and each having it's own htaccess file?

Thanks. I have done another ticket a month or so back but I am not sure how to change the questions, so I apologise for the similar ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You rule only redirects `non-www` http URLs to SSL version of your site. To redirect both `non-www` and `www` http versions , replace your first rewrite block with the following

```
RewriteCond ℅{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mjvlaw\.co\.uk 
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mjvlaw.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before you test this.

Comment: this is still not redirecting to the https version after checking on that site. Is it working for you? http://www.mjvlaw.co.uk/

Comment: @ChrisD maybe you are behind a proxy server. Proxy server doesnt recognize the `℅{HTTPS}` variable. Try replacing the first condition with `RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_SCHEME} http$ [OR]`

Comment: unfortunately, that has not worked. Very strange how it works on one of the domains but not the domain that is the main one. If you are not sure after that change do not worry.